# Google Search Console - Which Properties Should I Add?

Tags: google-search-console

In an automated email from Google's Search Console...

> **1**  *Add all your website versions*
>
> Make sure you add separate Search Console properties for all URL variations that your site supports, including https, http, www, and non-www.

What does "... site supports ..." mean?

I'm trying to do what Google suggests in this [knowledge base article about using canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066), but it isn't totally clicking in my head just yet. My end goal is that I want Google to understand my site is available at **`https://www.`**`example.com/` and every other permutation is incorrect. Should I add `http://www.example.com/`, `http://example.com/`, and `https://example.com/` as properties to my Google Search Console?

I think I have (correctly) set up my `.htaccess` file so that all naked and/or http requests will be 301'd to `www.` prefixed and https requests.

**`public_html/.htaccess`**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google clearly says, you should add all versions of your site as follows
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
and the 2 https versions.

```
  What does "... site supports ..." mean?
```

Well, it means whatever URLs are supported by your site i.e. are served by your site. Google will treat each of them differently and you have to keep checking all the four to ensure that most of your traffic is moving to your canonical property i.e. https://www version in your case.

I would suggest you add all four, and periodically keep checking - Doing by practice is sometimes the best way to clear your head.