# If I use canonical tag then, it's necessary to submit "www" and "non-www" versions on GSC?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Google webmaster tools says: Make sure you add both "www" and "non-www" versions for your site. Also, if you use the HTTPS protocol, add those variations as well. So I've added all the FOUR versions to google webmaster tools. Is this a correct process?

What is the best practice for submit canonical website, submit by domain or URL prefix?

[image]

Comment: See also [If redirects for variations are in place, can I safely consolidate down to one Google Search Console property?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119210/if-redirects-for-variations-are-in-place-can-i-safely-consolidate-down-to-one-g) and [Should I submit https:// and http:// in Google Search Console both with and without the www?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/should-i-submit-https-and-http-in-google-search-console-both-with-and-with)

Comment: See also [Google Search Console - Which Properties Should I Add?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92855/google-search-console-which-properties-should-i-add)